# mysql query - use in & order by & limit together

Tags: mysql, sql

When running query in `mysql`, got some strange result:

**SQL 1:**

```
 SELECT *
 FROM location
 WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%','SZ','%')
   AND `STATUS` = 1
   AND location_level IN (4,3)
 ORDER BY location_level;
```

**SQL 2:**

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM location
 WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%','SZ','%')
   AND `STATUS` = 1
   AND location_level IN (4,3)
 ORDER BY location_level
 LIMIT 2;
```

The only difference between the 2  sql is that `Sql 2` has a `limit` part.

**Execute result:**

> - `Sql 1` has `1` row,
> - `Sql 2` has `0` rows

**Question:**

I expect `Sql 2` should also get result, but it didn't, any idea?

---

**@Update:**

The mysql on windows seems to be quite old, I failed to stop it, it seems crashed, so I uninstalled it, and then download mysql5.6, and installed, now the 2 sql works the same.

Sorry for the non-sense issue. With mysql5.6 it's ok now.

Comment: Share sample data to reproduce it

Comment: Stupid question, but did the contents of `location` change between invocations of SQL 1 and SQL 2?

Comment: Try in second example `LIMIT 0, 2` or `LIMIT 2 OFFSET 0` to specify offset explicitly

Comment: @lad2025 I am prepareing, the table is huge..

Comment: @eggyal Nope, I am testing locally.

Comment: @EricWang Use http://sqlfiddle.com for demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it on [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and got the result as expected which is 1.
I have gone through the mySQL docs as well and found following

> If you
>   combine **LIMIT row_count** with **ORDER BY**, **MySQL ends the sorting as soon
>   as it has found the first row_count rows of the sorted result, rather
>   than sorting the entire result.****(which in your case it should have return 1 if in somehow the result didn't gets changed in middle)** If ordering is done by using an index,
>   this is very fast. If a filesort must be done, all rows that match the
>   query without the LIMIT clause are selected, and most or all of them
>   are sorted, before the first row_count are found. After the initial
>   rows have been found, MySQL does not sort any remainder of the result
>   set

Comment: I think it's due to the quite old mysql on windows, and now I re-installed a new mysql, it works as expect. Usually I work on linux, so this windows version was left there for years ... I didn't upgrade it, it has name `mysql 6.0` I don't remember where it's downloaded years ago.